# How I can transfer all messages from System.Diagnostics.Trace to ILogger?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a lot of code where I use System.Diagnostics.Trace. I want to save all messages to file using ILogger, nlog. How I can do it?

Comment: Do you use a logging library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own TraceListener, which would look something similar to this

```cs
   // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener?view=netframework-4.7.2
   public class LoggerTraceListener : TraceListener
  {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public LoggerTraceListener(ILogger logger) {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
      _logger.LogInformation(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
      _logger.LogInformation(message);
    }
  }
```

And then, in the Startup, you could register that listener

```cs
public class Startup
{
    // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var logger = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILogger<Startup>>();

        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-and-initialize-trace-listeners#to-create-and-use-a-trace-listener-in-code
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new LoggerTraceListener(logger));  
    }
}
```

This would output to an ILogger, you could configure your logger factory to output to a file.

Comment: Once you have Trace messages flowing to the logger, how can you configure the TraceSwitch levels without the .config file? Or is it possible to configure them from appsettings.json?

Comment: Responding to my earlier question - from what I can tell, the TraceSwitch implementation for netcoreapp does not get populated from the ConfigurationManager (also gutted), nor do instances with the same name share values. So my only answer seems to be to set them directly

Answer (score 1):

You can't. However, if you work the other way around, i.e. adding the Trace provider to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, and then logging with `ILogger`. messages will go out to Trace, and any other logging you have setup.

If you're trying to capture logging done by the framework, .NET Core already uses Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. You simply need to change your log level appropriately so it captures Debug and Trace levels, in addition to the default of Info or higher. Additionally, if you're only interested in logging from certain components, you can specify log levels and providers by namespace. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-filtering) have all the information you need there.