# Write Trace Logs to text file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, trace

I have an application written in `.NetFramework 4.5` and the trace logs are added in the simplest possible way:

```cs
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Method in: ");
    //
    //
    //
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Method out: ");
```

We use to write the trace logs into a text file using the `<configuration />` tag in `web.config`.

```xml
    <configuration>
      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
          <listeners>
            <add name="app-logger" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="logfile.txt" />
            <remove name="Default" />
          </listeners>
        </trace>
      </system.diagnostics>
    </configuration>
```

I'm trying to implement the same functionality in `.NetCore 3.1` but where should I place the `<configuration />` tag?

Comment: You can [redirect all traces to your `ILogger`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54537694/2698119), and then configure that logger to output to a file.

Comment: @Métoule - Thanks for the suggestion. It will work to achieve the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serilog for logging into Text file.
https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/aspnet-core-file-logger/